# Error parsing XML: unbound prefix in custom view

Tags: android, xml

I tried customizing a view from a library I'm using for my android app. The default xml code for this looks like this:

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardView
            android:id="@+id/carddemo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="12dp"/>
```

This works without any problems. But when I add a new line in the element, to use my custom layout, I get an error in the opening line, that you can see in the title of this question: This is the line I was adding in the end:

```
        card:card_layout_resourceID="@layout/custom_layout" />
```

This is also exactly the code that was used as an example in the docs of the library.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You probably forgot to "define" a namespace for the custom attribute `card`. So add this to your *root-view* in your `xml-file`:

```
xmlns:card="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

Comment: That works and also seems logical when I look at it this way. Sadly the tutorial I used didn't cover this part.